# sqlite3.OperationalError "too many SQL variables" when selecting rows from given range

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a website hosted on a Linux server. The backend is done in Flask, and the database I am using is SQLite3 (with Flask-SQLAlchemy). The problem is that I needed to do a large query like in the next line.

```
for lhour in hour.query.filter(hour.id.in_([id_hour for id_hour in range(start_at , hour.query.count()+1)])):
```

The code above just does a query for all the hours where the id is bigger than the `start_at` variable, however the number of rows in the hours table is well over 999 (the maximum allowed in SQLite3 prior to version 3.32.0) so this would throw an error whenever the `start_at` variable was lower than 1600 (as the number of rows in the hour table is 2600).

After reading that for versions after 3.32.0 the maximum allowed is 32766, I compiled the source code and installed version 3.34.1 of SQLite3 on my Linux server.

[image: Preview of currently installed version on the server]

However, the line of code would still throw the exact same error, so what version of SQLite3 does Flask-SQLAlchemy use and how do you set it so it uses the correct one?

[image: Error 1-st page]
[image: Error 2-nd page]

Answer (score 3):

Selecting values from a numeric range by using `column.in_(list_of_values)` will lead to a query where literally every item in the `list_of_values` occurs as a variable in the query.

What's limited in SQLite is the number of variables in a single statement, certainly not the number of rows in a table (in practice – the theoretical limit is 2<sup>64</sup>)!

See sections 9 and 13 in https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html.

Use a simple comparison instead:

```
for lhour in hour.query.filter(hour.id >= start_at):
```

You do not need to check or install a particular SQLite version for that.

As a bonus, this only performs one query instead of two.